# fieldset legend position right not working in mPDF Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel-8, mpdf

I use `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` with Laravel 8 to generate PDFs 
in my Pdf page I puted a fieldset, I want to set legend in the right position, but it's not working, I tried `align=aright`, `float=right` , `text-align=right`  but nothing ... 
any helps ?

Comment: Please add a [repro] for debugging details. To place a legend at the right, you have to work with the margins of the legend.

Answer (score -1):

The legend of a fieldset is aligned with the margin. To place a legend at the right side of the fieldset you have to use: `margin-left: auto` because the value `auto` will consume all remaining space.

```css
legend {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  Empty Fieldset for Testing
</fieldset>
```

Comment: it's not working  in mPDF